# How can I keep a change in webpage's source each time I visit it?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, html, css

I use a crappy web-mail service (paid) which has a troubling interface. The area for reading emails is quite small and I have to scroll both ways to read each mail's content. Since I have no knowledge about web programming and markup syntax, I tried my best to go through the page-source and found a line that could potentially solve my issue:

```
<div class="main" style="width: 849px; height: 309px;">
<div class="left" data-unread="0" style="width: 211px"></div>
<div class="right" style="margin-left: 211px"></div>
```

Changing the first line's *849px* to something like *1200px* makes it better (no more horizontal scrolling). I was wondering if there was a way to make it stay this way every time I load the web site. I am using Firefox 33.0 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag & drop the link in [this JSBin snippet](http://jsbin.com/qamacu) to your browser's bookmark bar. Every time you have to change the width of the div on the desired page, click on the bookmarklet

The following is the bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0].style.width='1200px';})()
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly.